# how do i limit the number of characters in a string using mysql

Tags: mysql

Iam using this script:

```
$thisproductname_url=str_replace(" ", "-", $r["name"]); // replace a space with hyphen
$thisproductname_url = preg_replace( "/[^0-9a-zA-Z-]/", '', $thisproductname_url);
```

But the number of chracters in  the variable $thisproductname_url is sometimes too many (240+) and breaks the link.

Is there a way to limit the variable - $thisproductname_url - to say 200 chars?

Comment: Since the original string is user input, what about limiting the length of what the user can enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what this has to do with your str_replace and preg_replace, but if you want to cut off a string at 200 characters, just use substr [(manual)](http://www.php.net/substr). You can check the length first if you need.

Comment: I used:
    if (strlen($thisproductname_url) > 200) { 
    $thisproductname_url = substr($thisproductname_url, 0, -50); 
    }